# Replace resulting values with python split method

Tags: python, split

What I'm trying to do with a list of path's looking like:

```
['path/to/somewhere?id=6&name=Test', 'path/to/list?date=05222014&type=cal']
```

**my puesdocode:**

```
for each path with parameters:
    split path on character ? and &
    replace value after "=" with a value from self.fuzz_vectors
```

**My current code:**

```
def parse_paths(self):
    dictpath = []
    if self.path_object is not None:
        for path in self.path_object:
            self.params = path.split("?")[1].split("&") #split value after ? and after &
            #replace splitted string after '=' sign with self.value_path
        dictpath.append(self.params)
```

My code is somewhat there, but I'm a bit confused how to split the string after the equals sign as commented.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: I'm looking to add all the split strings into a dictionary (as I started to do) in the last line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you it must involve only split method and it cant involve any other string replacement methods or regular expressions. Anyway, this is one way of doing it without using any regular expressions or string replace method:

```
st = ['path/to/somewhere?id=6&name=Test', 'path/to/list?date=05222014&type=cal']
```

dictpath = {}

```
for path in st:
    params = path.split("?")[1].split("&") 
    out = list(map(lambda v: v.split("=")[0] +"=" + fuzz_vectors, params))
    dictpath[path] = out

print(dictpath)
```

gives:

```
{'path/to/list?date=05222014&type=cal': ['date=some_string', 'type=some_string'],    'path/to/somewhere?id=6&name=Test': ['id=some_string', 'name=some_string']}
```

Comment: To answer your question about - I would prefer to do it with split method, unless there is a better performing way to do it? Can you modify your answer, to append the 'out' values to a dictionary (as I had started to do) - would really appreciate it @Marcin .

Comment: @CodeTalk Your `dictpath` is a list, not a dictionary. I modified the code for dictionary, i.e.`dictpath = {}`.

Answer (score 0):

you might want to look at `urlparse` module:

```
>>> import urlparse
>>> print urlparse.parse_qs('path/to/somewhere?id=6&name=Test'.split('?')[1])
{'id': ['6'], 'name': ['Test']}
>>> print urlparse.parse_qs('path/to/list?date=05222014&type=cal'.split('?')[1])
{'date': ['05222014'], 'type': ['cal']}
```

then you can replace the values just by addressing the dict keys

Comment: I had look into this, but this seemed to be unnecssary as I already have the paths from the database by this point. I appreciate the answer though